# Storing multiple value in database using checkbox

Tags: php

I want to store both `$row_tbl['Course_ID']` and `$row_tbl['Section']` value in checkbox name variable. Basically I want to store course id and section in database by checking that field.

What can I do?

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
        $values = $_POST['check'];
        $valuesArr = array();   

        foreach ($values as $a){
            $valuesArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
        }

        $max = sizeof($values);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $max ; $i++) {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO course_reg (stu_id,course_id,section,semester,grade,status) VALUES ('$sesid','$valuesArr[$i]','????','Summer 2016','Z','a')";
            $reg = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
        }
    }
?>

<?php while($row_tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): ?>

    <tr class="success" style="font-size:12px;">

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value="<?php echo $row_tbl['Course_ID'] ?>" id="in" onclick="test()" />
        </td>

        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Course_ID'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Course_Title'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Section'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Time'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Day'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Dept'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_tbl['Capacity'] ?></td>

    </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain index value of each checkbox for getting checked checkbox values check below ex:

```
  $index = 0;
  while($row_tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
  <input type="checkbox" 
  name="<?php echo 'check['.$index.']['.$row_tbl['Course_ID']; ?> ]"            
  value=" <?php echo $row_tbl['Section'] ?> "/>
  <?php echo $row_tbl['Section'] ?> 

  $index++;
  }
```

At Php server page loop through index and call insert into DB logic